# Pass JS output into a DB via Flask

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, sqlite, flask

I am writing a website that has to display the IP and Location of 10 most recent users and store all the visits in a database. The website has to be coded in Flask and HTML/CSS/JS. I have already written a script that does `ipLookup()` in my `.js` file, but now I am having trouble with passing the `JS` data into my `python flask` app so that I can add it to my database. 

Overall, **how do I pass `JS` script output into `Python Flask`?**

TIA

**EDIT:** thank you for your quick responses they really helped and guided me to a solution. For future ref I recommend this article tho: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd POST the data from your JavaScript code to a Flask view, which can then do things with it. [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch),

```
const myIp = ipLookup();
fetch('/save-ip', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ip: myIp}),
}).then(r => {
  console.log(r);
}).catch(e => {
  alert('Error: ' + e);
});
```

and something like

```
@app.post("/save-ip")
def save_ip():
  data = request.get_json())
  print(data)
  # ... save ...
```